# How to draw different lines inside column of QTableView depending on data in cells in near column?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw lines inside column that show possible connections between different signals(Further, I also want to make radiobuttons on them to choose what connections are active).

But now I have trouble that delegates allow me to SetItemDelegate only for all column or all row. So I can't just make different blocks of this lines like vertical line, corner lines, horizontal line and then paint them depending on data in cells. I attached an example image. What should I use to draw something like this?

Something like:

Define a new style, override drawPrimitive method and do custom painting?

Could you show me an example, please?

Lines example

[image]

What I have for now

[image]

My main code for creating rows with signals(I take them from .txt file for simulation for now):

```
       int IPFilesize = IPfilespl.size();
   ui->CompTab->setRowCount(IPFilesize);

   for (int i = 0; i<IPFilesize; i++)
       {
           QWidget *ChBx = new QWidget();
           QCheckBox *pCheckBox = new QCheckBox();
           QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(ChBx);
           pLayout->addWidget(pCheckBox);
           pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
           pLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
           ChBx->setLayout(pLayout);
           ui->CompTab->setCellWidget(i, 0, ChBx);
           //connect(ChBx,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(checkboxClicked()));
       }

   for (int ii = 0; ii<IPFilesize; ii++)
       {
           ui->CompTab->setItem(ii, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(IPfilespl.at(ii)) );
           //connect(ChBx,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(checkboxClicked()));
       }
   ui->CompTab->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, new WireDelegateDown());
```

Header code

```
class WireDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate { protected:  void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& opt, const QModelIndex& index) const {

int x = opt.rect.x();
double y = opt.rect.y();
QPoint c = opt.rect.center();
double centerx = c.x();
double centery = c.y();
double r = opt.rect.right();
double width = opt.rect.width();
double height = opt.rect.height();
QPainterPath path;
path.addRect(centerx, centery-height/2, 5.0, height/2);
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.addRect(centerx, centery, width/2, 5.0);
path = path.simplified();
painter->drawPath(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your item delegate could be a subclass of [QAbstractItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html). Then you can set its type with a property like **shapeType** (or whatever you name it). Based on the shapeType, you can do internal painting stuff from within the reimplemented [paint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#paint) method.

```
void MyConnectionDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                           const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (m_shapeType  == ShapeType::horizontalLine) {
        //..... Your fancy drawings happens here based on shapetype
    } else if (m_shapeType  == ShapeType::verticalLine) {
    .
    .
    .
```

As I see in the picture (your desired result) it's not going to be simple and it can get quite complicated to implement such behavior. You will have to calculate the width, height, position of lines, colors, dots, arrows, nodes, etc for each delegate. When you exactly know which entities should be drawn in each cell, painting them using [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) is a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider whether QTableView is getting in the way more than it helps you. The built-in widgets are fantastic, but often, I've found that when I need to venture outside the realm of what they were specifically designed to do, I end up spending more time working around them than I get benefit. I don't know the right solution for what you're doing, but if it were me, I'd explore writing my own view based on QAbstractItemView and then just doing my own custom painting for the whole thing.

The downside of doing that is that QTableView provides a lot of interaction support for you, so if the interaction is a big benefit to you, then you have to write your own as well. So it's a trade-off. It's also a possibility that the built-in interaction for QTableView also gets in the way of what you're trying to do. It can go either way.